# Can anyone help me to write the regular expression to match a number if the next line begins with a word?

Tags: regex, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

In Power Automate Desktop, I want to match `2,021` which is present at the second last word on the third line with the respect of `Demand` which the first word of the fourth line.

Input:

```
Days of
Service
Electric 0156887974 02/24/23 60,170 01/24/23 58,149 1 2,021 31
Demand 0156887974 02/24/23 9.62 01/24/23 10.39 1 9.62 31
MESSAGE from KUA
```

I have tried this ex:
(?<=Days of+\r\nService+\r\nElectric ............................................)......
from first word of this line but this line have multiple dynamic values and characters of these dynamic values have also increase or decrease and result fail the expression. So now I notice that if I search backward from the value "Demand" ,its not affected by other dynamic values. This value is 4 digit characters with comma(,).

Comment: Hello, regex for what? Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I extract this dynamic value from the whole pdf document base on RegEx in power automate desktop

Comment: Sure; I can help; What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried this  ex: (?<=Days of+\r\nService+\r\nElectric ............................................)......   from first word of this line but this line have multiple dynamic values and characters of these dynamic values have also increase or decrease and result fail the expression.
So now I notice that if  I search backward from the value "Demand" ,its not affected by other dynamic values. But i didn't get the expression.

Comment: Some more requirements should be provided as it's still pretty unclear - e.g. is the number format always the same, digits with comma, are there supposed to be multiple matches, etc. Edit the post with them to be **as specific as possible**.

Comment: Please edit your question to post more details

Comment: @ShaikhMohammadZulqarnain - That should be part of your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Power Automate Desktop uses .NET regex engine, you can use:

```
\d,\d{3}(?= [\d.,]+\nDemand)
```

Explantation:

- `\d,\d{3}` - digit followed by comma and 3 digits, as you specified
- `(?= [\d.,]+\nDemand)` - positive lookahead of space followed by some digits, dots or commas (could make it more accurate and validate number if needed), newline and `Demand` word

[Demo with further explantation](https://regex101.com/r/TAMl2t/3).